# Error while generating trace file in Vampirtrace

Tags: environment-variables, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I want to do profiling for my parallel processing code that I have wrote using OpenMPI library. I am trying to use vampirtrace for this purpose. I compiled my code using command

```
vtcxx -vt:cxx mpic++ ../src/parallel_encode_nonBlocking.cpp -o parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe
```

and I am trying to run my code using following command to generate trace file,

```
mpirun -np 4 parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe  ducks.m2v ducks11.h264
```

here last 2 names are names of input and output files that are required by code. But after running code I am getting following errors,

```
/usr/bin/nm: '/home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad': No such file
/usr/bin/nm: 'MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe': No such file
VampirTrace: FATAL: Failed to execute /usr/bin/nm -B --demangle --line-numbers /home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe
Please set the environment variable VT_GNU_NM to the 'nm' command including command line switches which lists symbol/addresses of an object file in BSD-style or set VT_GNU_NMFILE to a pre-created symbol list file.
/usr/bin/nm: '/home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad': No such file
/usr/bin/nm: 'MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe': No such file
/usr/bin/nm: '/home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad': No such file
/usr/bin/nm: 'MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe': No such file
VampirTrace: FATAL: Failed to execute /usr/bin/nm -B --demangle --line-numbers /home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe
Please set the environment variable VT_GNU_NM to the 'nm' command including command line switches which lists symbol/addresses of an object file in BSD-style or set VT_GNU_NMFILE to a pre-created symbol list file.
/usr/bin/nm: VampirTrace: FATAL: Failed to execute /usr/bin/nm -B --demangle --line-numbers /home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe
Please set the environment variable VT_GNU_NM to the 'nm' command including command line switches which lists symbol/addresses of an object file in BSD-style or set VT_GNU_NMFILE to a pre-created symbol list file.
'/home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad': No such file
/usr/bin/nm: 'MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe': No such file
VampirTrace: FATAL: Failed to execute /usr/bin/nm -B --demangle --line-numbers /home/rishikesh/Videos/Documents/Rishikesh_MTP_data/Harshad MTP/MTP/encoder_experiments/ffmpeg_transcode/bin/parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe
Please set the environment variable VT_GNU_NM to the 'nm' command including command line switches which lists symbol/addresses of an object file in BSD-style or set VT_GNU_NMFILE to a pre-created symbol list file.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in `VampirTrace` with spaces in the absolute path name to your application binary. To work around that you can either remove the space from the "Harshad MTP" directory, or manually execute

```
nm parallel_encode_nonBlocking_trace.exe > nm.file
export VT_GNU_NMFILE="$PWD/nm.file"
```

The error message is quite clear about that if you actually carefully read it.

Comment: @rishi007bansod if the answer solved your problem, please accept / upvote it.